# Why netCDF raster files get so big compared to TIFF files

Tags: geotiff-tiff, netcdf

For a project I'm involved in, I'm currently researching the recommended standard file type for sharing raster data.

So far, I wasn't quite happy with the `.tif` files we used, as they came with many auxiliary files in some cases (like `.ftw`, `.tif.aux`, `.tif.vat.dbf` etc.). So, in order to have self-contained raster files, I tried `.netCDF` files instead. However, then I noticed you get much larger files when you store exactly the same raster in a `.netCDF` file instead of a `.tif`, more than 8 times larger, in this case:

```
# reproducible example in R
require(terra)
require(dplyr)

r <- rast(ncol=10, nrow=10, xmin=-150, xmax=-80, ymin=20, ymax=60, vals = runif(100))

r %>% 
  writeCDF('example_raster.cdf')

r %>% 
  writeRaster('example_raster.tif')

tif_size <- 'example_raster.tif' %>% 
  file.info() %>% 
  pull(size)

netcdf_size <- 'example_raster.cdf' %>% 
  file.info() %>% 
  pull(size)

netcdf_size/tif_size
#[1] 8.452123
```

Why do netCDF raster files get so big compared to TIFF files?

Comment: Why would the existance of metadata cause unhappiness? The TIFF specification is 37 years old, and the "current" version released over 31 years ago. GeoTIFF is a bit younger, at 23. Of course there will be ancillary files. But it's always supported compression algorithms.

Comment: What does `gdalinfo` say for the resulting files?

Comment: I guess that you did not compress your NetCDF. Deflate compression method is available. About the TIFF sidecars, I have never seen .ftw. Is that a mistyped .tfw? The tif.aux file typically contains the image statistics but it may contains some other information as well. The .vat.dbf contains a raster attribute table. It may be safe just to delete the sidecar files. Please share some test data. Is it possible to save the image statistics and raster attribute tables into NetCDF?